# Python Subprocess with double quotes

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, popen

I've got a Docker Service Log that takes in NiFi Actions and I want to capture only Log Entries that include "Successfully sent" *and* "Failed to process session" (and nothing more). They should be captured in a directory called "nifi_logs" in the present working directory. I need to do all of this using Python.

This is what I got so far:

```
docker_log = 'docker service logs nifi | grep -e "Successfully sent" -e "Failed to process session" >> $PWD/nifi_logs/nifi1.log'
subprocess.Popen(docker_log, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I believe `subprocess.Popen()` is having difficulty with the double quotes used in the `grep`, as `nifi1.log` is completely empty. If the first command looks like the following:

```
docker_log = 'docker service logs nifi | grep session >> $PWD/nifi_logs/nifi1.log'
```

The Python code works just fine and captures all log entries with "session" in `nifi1.log`. As I explained above though, I need to grep for 2 kinds of Log Entires and both include multiple words, meaning I need to use quotes.

If I were to just run this command on the Terminal without Python:

```
docker service logs nifi | grep -e "Successfully sent" -e "Failed to process session" >> $PWD/nifi_logs/nifi1.log
```

The log generates the entries just fine, so I know the Docker Service command is written correctly.

I've tried switching the single and double quotes around, I've tried using `\"` instead of `"` within the single quotes ... `nifi1.log` continues to be empty.

I also tried using `os.system()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`, but I run into the same problem (and I believe `os.system()` is somewhat deprecated).

Any ideas what I'd need to do to change what `docker_log` equals so that it will properly grep for the 2 search criteria? So you're aware: this question is not asking HOW I generate the log entries (I know what Docker Services I'm looking for, they generate properly), just what I need to do to get Python Subprocess Popen to accept a command with quotes in it.

Comment: Hello @PillagingProgrammer, and welcome to StackOverflow! I tested on [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@david_why/Python-Subprocess-with-Quotes#main.py) and it worked. Which Python version are you using? Also, can you post an example of the results of `docker service logs nifi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your assistance [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13951118/david). Looking at your example, I found a solution: I removed `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` from `subprocess.Popen` and now it accepts double quotes just fine!

```
docker_log = 'docker service logs nifi | grep -e "Successfully sent" -e "Failed to process session" >> $PWD/nifi_logs/nifi1.log'
subprocess.Popen(docker_log, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```